# ¿Cómo traigo la clave y el valor juntos de un .map?

Tags: javascript, map

Estoy trabajando con un odontodiagrama (diagrama que utilizan los dentistas para marcar los distintos trabajos realizados en los dientes) el mismo trabaja eligiendo el tipo de trabajo que se ha realizado marcando arriba y luego señalando el diente, yo nesesito obtener el tipo de trabajo a realizar y la posición del diente para guardarlo en base de datos y posteriormente mostrarlo en otra parte del sistema, para poder realizar esto coloque *inputs* tipo *checkbox* de forma oculta detrás de cada pieza del diente.

```
 createOdontogram();
    $(".click").click(function() {
        var control = $("#controls").children().find('.active').attr('id');          
        console.log('diente: '+$(this).attr('id'))
        var position = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).find('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', 'true');
```

Utilizo `.map` para poder recorrerlos y me genera un array de esta forma:

```
Array(6) [ "exodoncia", "restauración defectuosa", "provisional realizada", "c1i8", "c1i7", "c1i6" ]
```

Yo nesesito que me devuelva clave y valor de este modo:

```
Array(6) [ "exodoncia","c1i8","restauración defectuosa", "c1i7", "provisional realizada", "c1i6" ]
```

Código:

```
$(document).on('click','.cit_odo', function(){
       var checkedBox = $.map($('#odonto').find("input:checked"), 
           function(val) {
                return val.value, val.id;
//Array(6) [ "exodoncia", "restauración defectuosa", "provisional realizada", "c1i8", "c1i7", "c1i6" ]  es lo que trae
// Array(6) [ "exodoncia","c1i8","restauración defectuosa", "c1i7", "provisional realizada", "c1i6" ] del modo que nesesito           
             });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías formar un objeto al momento de realizar el `map`, así:

```
var checkedBox = $.map($('#odonto').find("input:checked"), 
                     function(val) {
                        return { "trabajo":val.value, "diente": val.id};
```

De esa manera tienes un arreglo de tipo:

```
Array(6) [ {"trabajo: "exodoncia", "diente": "c1i8"},{"trabajo": "restauración defectuosa", "diente": "c1i7"}, {"valuetrabajo: "provisional realizada", "diente": "c1i6"} ]
```

Comment: gracias por tu pronta respuesta lo intente del modo que me aconsejaste pero me trae el arreglo de este modo Array(6) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]

Comment: Para obtener el arreglo como deseas Array(6) [ "exodoncia","c1i8","restauración defectuosa", "c1i7", "provisional realizada", "c1i6" ], te recomiendo realizar un reduce y en el acumulador agregar los elementos del modo que necesitas.

Comment: te agradezco el consejo e estado documentandome un poco puesto que aun soy novata en javascript y hay cosas que no se aun ,si pudieras darme un indicio de como utilizaría el reduce me seria de mucha ayuda claro si puedes y muchas gracias de veras.